# Rails finding a database object object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every user in my database has a first name.  How can I find a user by their first name?  I'm trying to write this function in a less stupid way.

```
def find_by_name(name)
    User.find_each{|u|
    return u if u.first_name == name
  }
  return nil
end
```

I assumed this would work, but it doesn't.

```
>> u = User.first
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 41, first_name: "Justin", last_name: "Bieber", created_at: "2011-11-13 23:13:23", updated_at: "2011-11-13 23:13:23"> 
>> u = User.first(:first_name => "Justin")
ArgumentError: Unknown key: first_name
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:44:in `assert_valid_keys'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:43:in `each_key'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:43:in `assert_valid_keys'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/spawn_methods.rb:123:in `apply_finder_options'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:119:in `first'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `__send__'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `first'
from (irb):8
```

My model looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.where(:first_name => name).first`

This will translate roughly into this:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name=?`

(and it will bind the parameter to the string passed in).

Answer (score 2):

There should be a built-in, no?

```
User.find_by_first_name("Izzy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first names are not unique, you could either get all those that match or just the first one.

`User.find(:all, {:first_name => name})`

or

`User.find(:first, {:first_name => name})`